# Inner Join retornando vazio

Tags: mysql

Tenho um *SELECT* para retornar uma lista de produtos, mas quero que eles sejam diferenciados por entrada e saída, contém e não contém...

**Obs:** QUERO PEGAR A ÚLTIMA MOVIMENTAÇÃO DE CADA PRODUTO

Select que possuo até o momento

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM EstoqueGeral e
LEFT OUTER JOIN (

SELECT  * 
FROM produto_movimento 
GROUP BY codigoproduto
) AS mvp ON mvp.codigoproduto = e.codigo2

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM estoque_movimentacao
GROUP BY idmov
) AS em ON mvp.idmov = em.idmov

LEFT OUTER JOIN (

SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM clientes2
GROUP BY ID_cliente
) AS c ON c.cpf = em.cliente

ORDER BY `mvp`.`id_pm`  DESC
LIMIT 15
```

**RETORNO**

[image: RETORNO]

**TABELA MOVIMENTACAO 2**

[image: TABELA MOVIMENTACAO]

**TABELA PRODUTOS 3**

[image: TABELA PRODUTOS]

**TABELA PRODUTOS MOVIMENTADO 4**

[image: TABELA PRODUTOS MOVIMENTADO]

**TABELA CLIENTES 5**

[image: TABELA CLIENTES]

Comment: você tem algum erro como retorno ou dados não desejados ?

Comment: ele nao retorna erro, ele simplesmente não retorna as outras tabelas

Answer (score 0):

não deve estar aparecendo por causa do INNER JOIN muda para LEFT JOIN so para ver se retorna ou tenta isso mais vai ficar pesado ou algo do genero

```
 SELECT * FROM EstoqueGeral e
    LEFT JOIN produto_movimento mvp 
        ON 
            mvp.codigoproduto = e.codigo2 AND 
            mvp.codigoproduto  = ( SELECT mvp2.codigoproduto FROM produto_movimento ORDER BY mvp2.codigoproduto DESC LIMIT 1 )
```

Comment: Agora retorna null

Comment: Essa query nao esta juntando a tabela cliente como faço para pegar, só seguir essa lógica?

Comment: sim adiciona outros left